# How to access DropDown values in Struts 2 Action

Tags: struts2

My requirement is, at beginning I want to show users data on page and when user make changes in form, I want to access changed data.

Below is my code in Action class,

```
public class DisplayData extends ActionSupport implements ModelDriven<List<User>>, Preparable  {
private List<User> userList;
@Override
 public void prepare() throws Exception {
 userList = new ArrayList<User>();
 userList.add(new User("Demo","N"));
 userList.add(new User("Demo1","Y"));
 userList.add(new User("Demo2","Y"));
 userList.add(new User("Demo3","N"));
}
@Override
public List<User> getModel() {
  return userList;
}
public String execute(){
for (User value: userList) {
   System.out.println(value.getName() +":"+value.getFlag());
}
return "success";
}
public List<User> getUserList() {
  return userList;
}
public void setUserList(List<User> userList) {
   this.userList = userList;
 }
}
```

User class,

```
public class User implements Serializable
{
   private String name;
   private String flag;
   public User() {}
   public User(String name,String flag) {
     super();
     this.name = name;
     this.flag = flag;
   }
   public String getName() {
      return name;
   }
   public void setName(String name) {
     this.name = name;
   }
   public String getFlag() {
     return flag;
   }
   public void setFlag(String flag) {
      this.flag = flag;
   }
  }
```

Code in Jsp page,

```
<s:form name="getData" action="getData" method="post">
<table>
<s:iterator value="model" status="rowStatus">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <s:textfield name="model[%{#rowStatus.index}].name" value="%{model[#rowStatus.index].name}"/>
      <s:select name="%{model[#rowStatus.index].flag}" value="%{model[#rowStatus.index].flag}"
       list="#{'Y':'Yes','N':'No'}"  />
    </td>
   </tr>
 </s:iterator>
 </table>
  <s:submit name="ok" value="ok" />
</s:form>
```

When page get rendered, it shows appropriate value of textfield and dropdown. 
If I changed the values in Textfield and droprdown and submit the form then I am getting modified value of textfield but for the dropdwon it shows old value. How can I access selected value of dropdown?

Answer (score 0):

Got the answer... :)

It was syntax mistake. Instead of

```jsp
<s:select name="%{model[#rowStatus.index].flag}" value="%{model[#rowStatus.index].flag}"
   list="#{'Y':'Yes','N':'No'}"  />
```

Use

```jsp
<s:select name="model[#rowStatus.index].flag" value="%{model[#rowStatus.index].flag}"
   list="#{'Y':'Yes','N':'No'}"  />
```

I have used `%{ }` in `name` attribute..